# How can I create a table like Visual Studio's watch window?

Tags: c#, objectlistview

I want to display data about some objects in my program, in a way similar to how Visual Studio's watch window works - A tree list with two columns, name and value, with the ability to expand non-primitive members further as child nodes in the tree structure.

I've been trying to do this with ObjectListView, but I can't seem to get it to happen. OLV seems to want to stick the members in individual columns, horizontally, while I want them to be displayed vertically, under the parent object (if that makes sense).

Comment: Show what you have so far...

Answer (score 1):

For winforms project there is a control - PropertyGrid that does this almost automatically, you need to set some attributes on the properties: 
[ReadOnly(bool)] – is the property read only.
[Browsable(bool)] – is it browsable, i.e to show in the property grid or not.
[Category(string)] – the parent group of the property
[Description(string)] – the description. It is displayed on the bottom label when you select the property.
[DisplayName(string)]  - you can override the display name.
Additional information you can find here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa302326.aspx